# Binomial coefficient asymptotics

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, asymptotics

What is the probability that the number of heads in $n$ fair coin tosses is exactly $\lfloor n/2 + c\sqrt{n} \rfloor$
for $c \leq O(1)$, $n > \omega(1)$?

Of course the answer is
$$ \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2+c\sqrt{n} \rfloor}.$$

I have estimated this and found it to be

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\Theta(c^2)}.$$

Is this correct? Is there a good name/reference for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a special case of the [de Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

If it was
$$A_n=\frac 1{2^n} \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+c \sqrt{n}}=\frac 1{2^n} \frac {\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+c \sqrt{n}+1)\,\,\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-c \sqrt{n}+1)}$$ taking logarithms, using three times Stirling approximation and exponentiating again
$$A_n=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}\,\, e^{-2 c^2}\,\left( 1-\frac{16 c^4-24 c^2+3}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$ You could do the same kind of expansion using the bounds of the floor function.